# Comparing bitwise AND query between SQL Server and MongoDB

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

I am currently working on an application that needs to make a bitwise & operation against a binary data whose length can be 200 bytes.

My first question is witch type of database is better to make queries that have this requirement. I have done tests on MongoDB and SQL Server to compare a NO-SQL database vs a SQL, and in both cases I have found enough problems to solve this requirement.

In SQL Server, what you need to do it is the following:

On the basis of that I have a table called "Packages" made up of a field called "Code" of binary type (200), all you should be able to do is the following query:

```
DECLARE @filter BINARY (200)
SET @filter = 0x0000 ... 042E --whatever

SELECT *
FROM Packages
WHERE Code & @filter = Code
```

Unfortunately, this query can not be carried out because SQL Server does not allow the operation & between two binary data. One way that occurred to me to solve this problem is by doing the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Packages
WHERE SUBSTRING (Code, 0, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 0, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 0, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 8, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 8, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 8, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 16, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 16, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 16, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code 24, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 24, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code 24, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 32, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 32, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 32, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 40, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 40, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 40, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 48, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 48, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 48, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 56, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 56, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 56, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 64, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 64, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 64, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 72, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 72, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 72, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 80, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 80, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 80, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 88, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 88, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 88, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 96, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 96, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 96, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 104, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 104, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 104, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 112, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 112, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 112, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 120, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 120, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 120, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 128, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 128, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 128, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 136, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 136, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 136, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 144, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 144, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 144, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 152, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 152, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 152, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 160, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 160, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 160, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 168, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 168, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 168, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 176, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 176, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 176, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 184, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 184, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 184, 16) AND
      SUBSTRING (Code, 192, 16) & CAST (SUBSTRING (@filter, 192, 16) as bigint) = SUBSTRING (Code, 192, 16)
```

In this way it works, but I fear that this should not scale well ...

On the other hand, I have not found a suitable solution with MongoDB, as the operator $bit can only be used on upgrades, not queries. You could find a solution somewhat contrived using the operator $bitsAnySet, but even so it would not be a final solution.

Can anyone help me how to approach this problem?

Thank you very much and greetings!

Comment: In SQL Server you could use a CLR function. This seems an odd basis for deciding between the two though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest, Martin. Sorry if I have formulated my question wrong. The issue is that I need to perform a "&" operation of a binary value of length 200 with:

* **In SQL Server**: one also binary length field 200 of a table can have millions of records.

* **In MongoDB**: a field that also keeps a binary value of length 200 of a collection of millions of documents.

I compare these two databases because they do not know:

1) If it can be solved in both cases.
2) If yes finally be resolved in both cases, what database would give me better performance?